# How to deploy pwa-studio on server in production mode?

Tags: magento2.3, pwa, pwa-studio, venia

I have successfully installed PWA-studio with Magento 2.3. But I am not able to run it on production mode on a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server so that we can access the PWA remotely but I am always able to start the application in development mode which only accessible locally.

How I can configure my server as well as the PWA-studio so that we can access the application remotely?

Comment: Can you please explain brief how you managed with pm2

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146329)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146329)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. git clone https://github.com/magento-research/pwa-studio.git
2. cd pwa-studio
3. npm install
4. cp packages/venia-concept/.env.dist packages/venia-concept/.env
5. edit and change MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL in packages/venia-concept/.env
6. In pwa-studio folder run:
   npm run build && NODE_ENV=production PORT=8000 npm run stage:venia

It will start the server on port 8000.

I used PM2 to manage node services.

(cd packages/venia-concept/ && NODE_ENV=production PORT=8000 node server.js)

Then I made Nginx proxy to pass connection from 8000 to 80 and 443

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the Nginx configuration so that it will be helpful?

Comment: When I used this command I getting below as output after the build has been completed.

Using environment variables from .env
Launching staging server...

NODE_ENV=production and no PORT set. Binding to localhost with random port
http://0.0.0.0:35210/
UPWARD Server listening in production mode.
GET / 200 357.467 ms - 2186

Comment: PWA studio docs state that `yarn run stage:venia`: "Generates build artifacts and runs the staging environment, which uses more compressed assets and *more closely reflects production*." That doesn't sound like *the way* to run in production, just something that more closely reflects real production setup. Would be nice to know what's a proper way to set it up for production use.